# How can different colours be assigned to lines?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Three sets of data generated from `AnglePath3D` and I'm stuck as to how to assign a different colour to each so they read better on screen. I'm not sure if I need to use another 3D plot function or just can't find the right graphics option?

```
Rasterize[
     Graphics3D[
      Line[#] &/@ {data1,data2,data3}, ColorRules->{data1->Red, data2->Blue, data3-
       >Black},ViewPoint->Front ],
      "Image"]
```

[image: Lines]

Comment: Under the "Neat Example" in the doc page for `Line` there are examples. Or you might look at the first example in the doc page for `Graphics3D` and see how different colored things are made and guess that each different thing could be replaced by a `Line[..]` object.

Comment: Also, read through the [Structure of Graphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html) tutorial.

Comment: Ok. I've had time to try both now. I failed. The best I was able to do was make them different `RandomColors`. Is it worth updating the question with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't tell us how you generated your data I will contrive some. The following generates three random walks in space, all starting the origin

```
SeedRandom[42];
Do[data[i] = Accumulate[Prepend[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}], {0, 0, 0}]], {i, 3}]
```

To give each walk its own color I will put each one in a list of form

```
{color, Line[points]}
```

To make these lists from the generated data points, I use `Transpose`.

```
lines = Transpose[{{Red, Blue, Black}, Table[Line @ data[i], {i, 3}]}];
```

Then the three data set can be visualized with the follow simple `Graphics3D` expression.

```
Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[4], lines}]
```

[image: plot]

In your case, you can replace

```
Table[Line @ data[i], {i, 3}]
```

with

```
Line /@ {data1, data2, data3}
```

#### Update

This update addresses an issue raised by the OP in a comment to this answer.

Mathematica has so many functions for building and restructuring lists that problems involving list manipulation almost always have more than one approach. If you were to look at the question that are tagged [list-manipulation](/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) (there are over 4000), you will see that many have quite a few solutions.

For example, I could have contrived my random walk data with `FoldList` rather than `Accumulate` and `Prepend`. I think many of Mathematica.SE regulars would argue using `FoldList` is more elegant.

```
SeedRandom[42];
{data1, data2, data3} = 
  Table[FoldList[Plus, {0, 0, 0}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}]], 3];
```

Then we can write

```
 walks = Line /@ {data1, data2, data3};
```

and

```
 colors = {Red, Blue, Black};
```

Given these definitions, here are four ways of generating the random walk graphics.

```
 Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[4], Transpose[{colors, walks}]}]
 Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[4], Thread[{colors, walks}]}]
 Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[4], MapThread[List, {colors, walks}]}]
 Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[4], Inner[Sequence, colors, walks, List]}]
```

All four expressions generate exactly the same graphics as shown above in the pre-update section of this answer.

The first two approaches, the ones using `Transpose` and `Thread`, are the ones I recommend as good Mathematica practice. The other two work but are somewhat cowboy-ish -- they just show off that I recognize that `MapThread` and `Inner`, two functions really intended for other purposes, can be adapted to work for this problem by a careful choice of arguments.

You should also note that the three variables `data1`, `data2`, and `data3` have been reduced to unnecessary intermediate variables by data generation method I use in this update. It would be better Mathematica practice to write

```
 SeedRandom[42];
 walks =
   Table[Line @ FoldList[Plus, {0, 0, 0}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}]], 3];
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I'm still wrapping my head around the structure of the MMA language. I played around with the `Transpose` step in my example and am wondering how you came up with that step? I can see what it does but there must be other ways to do that step?

Comment: @BBirdsell. I have made an update that I hope addresses the issues you raise in your comment.

Comment: Using `Transpose` feels wrong here, `Thread` seems more idiomatic.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, personally I always used `Transpose[]` before things like `Riffle[]` came along.

Comment: @J.M. the reason I think so is that `Transpose` is a "mathematical" function, while `Thread` feels "programmatic". I would not have been surprised if `Transpose` would not work on something like `{{1,2,3},{{4,5},{6},{7,8,9}}}` because of the raggedness of this array, but turns out it handles this gracefully.